# Cannot have multiple operations with the same operationId: clearCache

Tags: apiconnect

I have imported an API from swagger-UI and able to create an api and product,But when I am trying to publish ,I am getting this error.
 Cannot have multiple operations with the same operationId: clearCache
Cannot have multiple operations with the same operationId: getConfigurationJSON
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the error message, each operationId must be unique across all operations. This is further explained in the following Swagger-API issue and specification:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1146

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-5

> **operationId**: Unique string used to identify the operation. The id MUST
>   be unique among all operations described in the API. Tools and
>   libraries MAY use the operationId to uniquely identify an operation,
>   therefore, it is recommended to follow common programming naming
>   conventions.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I'm adding same operation name in post and put method. I have 3 endpoints get, post, put. still, I'm wondering why I'm not getting this error with Get & Post method.

Answer (score 0):

> If you add the --skip-validation flag only one of the getByID
>   operations will be generated
>   https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1146#issuecomment-270006562